# Replacing all charecters exept the wanted ones

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace all characters from my strings except for the ones, the user wants to keep, I really don't know how to do this...

Code so far:

```
using System;
class replace 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        string [,] masivs = new string[5,5]
        {
            {"kabacis", "burkans", "kartupelis", "rutks", "kaposts" },
            {"annanas", "banans", "bumbieris", "abols", "kivi"},
            {"mellene", "kazene", "avene", "zemene", "bruklene"},
            {"zilonis", "zirafe", "zebra", "lauva", "antilope"},
            {"lacis", "vilks", "zakis", "lapsa", "kurmis"}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < masivs.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < masivs.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(masivs[i, j]+" " );
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        char ch;

        Console.Write("Enter the charecter you wish to keep: ");
        ch = Console.ReadLine()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: replace by..what?  could you precise...what you have and what you want...its not very clear, for example if i want to keep i, what is your final result you want?

Comment: Can you add an example of what are your inputs and your expected output?